# Не могу разобраться с проблемой отправки сообщений с сайта

Tags: backend, hosting

Обратился в тех.поддержку они подсказали,что проблема в том,что скрипт обращается не по верному пути он ищет файл smart.php в корне,а не в папке домена. А как исправить это ошибку не получается

Comment: Исправить в скрипте путь к smart.php

Comment: Начинайте путь от текущей : `./smart.php` или `<?php echo getcwd() ; ?>/smart.php`

Comment: Благодарю, в конце URL необходимо было прописать /